# Factoring $b^5-a^5$ by $b^3-a^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I would like to factor the multivariate polynomial $b^5-a^5$ into something multiplied by $b^3-a^3$. I'm having a lot of trouble with this. I have attempted is as follows.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{b^5-a^5}{b^3-a^3}&=b^2\frac{b^3}{b^3-a^3}-a^2\frac{a^3}{b^3-a^3}\\
&=b^2\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^3}-a^2\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^3}
\end{align*}$$

**EDIT:** I noticed that if I multiplied $b^3-a^3$ and $b^2+a^2$ I get

$$(b^3-a^3)(b^2+a^2)=b^5-a^5+a^2b^2(b-a)$$

So

$$(b^3-a^3)\left(b^2+a^2-\frac{a^2b^2(b-a)}{b^3-a^3}\right)=b^5-a^5$$

Using the same reasoning/procedure, I get that $b^3-a^3=(b-a)(b^2+a^2+ab)$, so now I have

$$b^5-a^5=\left(b^2+a^2-\frac{a^2b^2}{a^2+ab+b^2}\right)(b^3-a^3)$$

Is this right? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hint: numerator and denominator are multiples of b-a

Comment: @vvnitram See my edit.

Comment: Why do you think it can be done? $x^3-1$ does not divide $x^5-1$ so the corresponding homogeneous polynomial cannot be factorized either.

Comment: @frank000 Calculating the moment of inertia of a spherical shell of uniformly distributed mass with inner radius $a$ and outer radius $b$ gives you a term $\rho (b^5-a^5)$, where $\rho$ is the mass density. Usually though, we are interested in putting the moment of inertia in terms of the total mass, which in this case would involve a term like $\rho(b^3-a^3)$. I just hadn't seen anybody actually try to non-trivially factor out $b^3-a^3$ from $b^5-a^5$.

Comment: $b^3-a^3$ is not a factor of $b^5-a^5$ in polynomials with rational coefficients.  You can do long division to get $b^5-a^5 = b^2(b^3-a^3)+a^3(b^2-a^2)$, if that helps.